# How do I send a JavaScript value to Rails Controller using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, controller

Within my `dashboard` page in my application I want to display a map legend that populates dynamically depending on the values given to the HTML that displays this legend.

This is what the legend should look like:
[image]

I am populating this legend using javascript; My JavaSCript function returns an array of nested hashes that would look something like this:

```
[
   {title: 'Downtown Loft', color:'#ade8ad'},
   {title: 'Midtown Mansion', color:'#bd95ff'}
]
```

### The Problem

In order to accomplish this, I need to be able to send the array above from my `pages.js.erb` file to my `pages_controller.rb` file, specifically to the `dashboard` action. Within this controller method, I will assign the data from my JavaScript to an instance variable called `@calendar_legend`

To verify this works, I will call `<%= @calendar_legend %>` in my `dashboard.html.erb` view and expect for it to show the array... unfortunately this does not work.

I've tried `render json: @calendar_legend` in my controller and I always get a `null` value when viewing that page.

Here's how I've tried sending the data to my controller:

```
function calendarLegend(){
  const legendarray = [
    {title: 'Downtown Loft', color:'#ade8ad'}, 
    {title: 'Midtown Mansion', color:'#bd95ff'}
  ]

  $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url: 'pages/dashboard',
      data: JSON.stringify(legendarray),
      contentType: 'application/json'
  });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  calendarLegend();
});
```

and here's how I've tried assigning it in my controller

```
def dashboard
   @calendar_legend = params[:legendarray]
   render json: @calendar_legend
end
```

and in my view

```
<%= @calendar_legend %>
```

This hasn't worked, among with any other solution that I found on Stackoverflow and various other sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are rendering the variable @calendar_legend that has not yet been set. Also the Ajax function does nothing to render the result on the page after it has been called.

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but here are some suggestions.

First, you could just set the @calendar_legend variable in the controller action that loads the dashboard.html.erb page (instead of calling another action once the page has loaded using Ajax). If you do this, you could just remove the Ajax function altogether.

Second, if you are set on trying to load data to change the legend after the page has loaded, you need to handle the response from the server. There are 2 ways I can think of to easily do this:

1. Add a response handler into the AJAX method (example from the jQuery Ajax docs - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) - in this example, the 'data' variable in the .done function would contain the value of @calendar_legend that you are rendering as json from the controller action, so you need to add it to the page:

   ```
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: "pages/dashboard",
     data: JSON.stringify(legendarray),
     contentType: 'application/json'
   }).done(function(data) {
     $('.div-with-calendar-legend-data-inside').html( data );
   });
   ```
2. You could also do this with Rails using a js.erb template with the same name as your controller action (instead of adding the response handler to your Ajax function). First you would modify your controller action to just set the variable and not render anything (and instead let Rails render the js.erb template):

   ```
   def dashboard
     @calendar_legend = params[:legendarray]
   end
   ```

Then create the template app/views/pages/dashboard.js.erb, and add something like this to it:

```
$('.div-with-calendar-legend-data-inside').html( <%= @calendar_legend %> );
```

Both of these options would require that you add a div (with a class or ID) in your view to add the @calendar_legend data into:

```
    <div class="div-with-calendar-legend-data-inside">
      <%= @calendar_legend %>
    </div>
```

Typically, I would only try to load data with Ajax if you are trying to reload the legend when the user makes a change on the page (ie. they select something from a dropdown or some other form input) - then you can send the data with Ajax to the controller and let it update the legend without refreshing the page. However, when doing that I would just use a form_tag and set remote: true on it, then use jquery to submit the form when the inputs change and handle the response with the js.erb template - I think this is cleaner than using the Ajax function.

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Thanks for the response... To be clear, I have no desire/preference to accomplish this with AJAX, i understand the main purpose of AJAX is to update the client in real-time without refreshes, that is not my intention. I only tried AJAX because it allows JS to talk to Rails. While your solution will probably work, I do not think it's ideal for my use case. It'd be great if you could elaborate on this portion of your response: "First, you could just set the @calendar_legend variable in the controller action ..."

Comment: I just realized I can probably do this entirely in Ruby

Comment: I solved this problem with using only ruby. For reasons unimportant, I was trying to generate this array with javascript which was completely unneccessary. I'm adding this comment because I feel this is not a good question, but the answer given was very informative!